# GridView returns null on renderRow React Native

Tags: react-native

Im using the [React Native Grid View](https://github.com/pavlelekic/react-native-gridview). The dataSource I'm using has been loaded correctly. Although, the renderRow doesn't receive the data.

```
getInitialState: function() {
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        var data = Array.apply(null, {length: 40}).map(Number.call, Number);

        return {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
        };
    },

_renderRow: function(rowData) {
        console.log(rowData);
        return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    },
render: function() {
        console.log(this.state.dataSource);
        return (
            <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                <GridView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow}
                    numberOfItemsPerRow={5}
                    removeClippedSubviews={false}
                    initialListSize={1}
                    pageSize={5}
                />
            </View>
        );
    },
```

The dataSource log shows that the data has been loaded. But the _renderRow method's console log prints null.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I think I found your answer. I had a look at the documentation and it seems you need to call `GridView.dataSource` rather than `ListView.dataSource`

https://github.com/jskuby/react-native-gridview

```
const dataSource = new GridView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
}).cloneWithRows(randomData);
```

Comment: Yes. That was it. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your _renderRow function declaration to ES6 fat arrow synatax? Is there a reason you're using ES5 syntax instead? I don't use createComponent ever, so I'm not too familiar with it's gotchas, so maybe just try this and see what happens. Otherwise, everything looks good to me.

```
_renderRow = (rowData) => {
  console.log(rowData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Chris. Yes I have tried it, but it does return the same null values. Can't seem to figure out what's the issue is.